# Passing javascript variables to php?

Tags: php, javascript, variables

ok so im trying to get a javascript variable into a php script, this would be an example,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
x = new Date()
</script>
<?php
$x = $_GET["x"]; 
?>
<p><?php echo $x ?></p>
```

i just cant get it to work! I need help please?

EDIT: well im just trying to get the hash from a url via javascript then put that in a php script.

Comment: Those two different languages execute in completely different places. The javascript executes on the client, and the php executes on the server. The only way to make one "see" the other is to use a communications framework like AJAX.

Comment: For the example, why not use php's date function?

Comment: well sorry Shad, :) im a little new to these areas of code, look at my profile im only 14

Comment: retracted, that was harsher than you deserved. Apologies ;)

Comment: lol its fine im just learning :)

Comment: This doesn't look like a duplicate to me. This question is about getting variables *from JavaScript to PHP*. The duplicate is about getting variables *from PHP to JavaScript*, which is entirely different. Voting to re-open.

Comment: Perhaps a more appropriate duplicate would be: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

PHP and javascript don't work like that.

PHP is a server-side language. While javascript is a clientside language.

There are still ways of passing data from the client-window to your server, via ajax, query parameters, cookies... But none will work in the same page.

Give us a clearer image on what you are trying to achieve and we will gladly help.

**UPDATE**

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    document.cookie = 'name=Khez' ;  
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php  
    var_dump($_COOKIE['name']);  
?>
```

Comment: Updated, post if you have issues.

Comment: @Khez, how exactly will i put the data into the cookie from js

Comment: depends on the type of data you need... you use the construct I used above it's a simple key-value pair. For your example you'd do `document.cookie= 'date='+(new Date()).getTime();` and in PHP you'd do `$x=date($_COOKIE['date']);`

Comment: im trying to get the hash and put it into a php

Comment: I don't know what hash you're referring to, but I believe it is outside the scope of your question. Readup on the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php) and [JS on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)

Comment: @deceze: `W3Schools should consider wikifying their content so the community could self-correct and keep the information up-to-date. Today, they do not even allow you to submit corrections on a page. They should.` I want that so much, you have no idea.

Comment: @Khez In the meantime, they may have decent introductions to the basics of a topic, but whenever linking to them we should include the link to w3fools as a caveat emptor. :)

Comment: @deceze: Would you be surprised if I say I will? ^^

Answer (score 6):

So there are 2 pages `page1.php` and `page2.php`

`page2.php` needs to pass JS variables to `page1.php`

We can do this by passing it as url variables from `page2.php` and get it in `page1.php` using `$_GET[]`.

`page2.php` (send JS variable)

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  var lati = location.lat();
  var longi = location.lng();
  document.location = 'http://www.rajak.me/index.php?addlat='+lati+'&addlong='+longi;   
});
</script>
```

`page1.php` (receive JS variable)

```
<?php    
  $addlat = $_GET['addlat'];
  $addlong = $_GET['addlong'];
?>
```

Comment: This one seems to be working fine for passing js variables of one php page to another page. This is what i was searching earlier. Thanks @Raja Krishnan for suggesting this idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following Javascript which will link to *somepage.php* with the variable in the Url

```
<script type="text/javascript">
x = new Date()
window.location.href = "somepage.php?w1=" + x;
</script>
```

This is the contents of *somepage.php* which recieves the variable and echoes it

```
<?php
   if (isset($_GET["w1"])) {
     $x = $_GET["w1"];
     echo $x;
   }else{
   echo 'no variable received';
   }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is "Server Side" code and javascript is client side code.  They don't interact...

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server-side~ all parsing is done on the server. JavaScript is client-side~ everything happens AFTER it get's to the client. If you need date in PHP, I recommend `time()` and or `date()`