# passing variables from javascript to php

Tags: php, javascript

i am passing variable from javascript php with the following code by using cookie.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gTest() {
               var country = 'hello testing';
    document.cookie = 'name=document.write(country);' ; 
         document.write(country);
}
gTest();
</script>


<?php  
echo "<br>";
     var_dump($_COOKIE['name']);  
?>
```

it works fine if we change to

```
    document.cookie = 'name=hello' ;
```

i want to pass variable value to php in same page...i don't want to send to another page.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing javascript variables to php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546675/passing-javascript-variables-to-php)

Comment: I would use query string parameters or a form to send data to the server

Comment: You need to learn about string concatenation in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

`$_COOKIE` is populated with the data sent from the browser to the server.

The JS to change the cookie won't run until the response is sent back and the JavaScript is executed.

The values in `$_COOKIE` won't update until you make a new HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XHR.

JavaScript (using jQuery):

```
$.ajax('script.php', { 
    data: { 'name': 'hello' }
});
```

PHP:

```
 var_dump($_GET['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant.

Ok, I think I got to explain. On your page, there is the Javascript first, then the PHP code, but it doesnt execute in that order. 
First the server execute the PHP code, send the page as HTML and the javascript is executed on the client side.

If you really dont want to reload the whole page, the only way to do it is to use an ajax request to a page where your PHP code is. Simply use JQuery and replace your PHP code with this :

`$('#result').load('showCookie.php');`

Content of showCookie.php will be your var_dump and the page will do exactly what you want, except that you have called an additional page with JQuery.